# svn setup with gpg-agent and pinentry-(tty|curses)

Tags: svn, gnupg

I am trying to setup svn to store my svn password in gpg-agent.

As there is no X on the box, my pinentry program would be either `pinentry-tty` or `pinentry-curses`.

Unfortunately. there seems to be a problem:

```
% svn up
Updating '.':
```

And now everything hangs. I checked with `strace` and the last message send to `gpg-agent` is `GET_PASSPHRASE`. I see in the process list, that a `pinentry` process is launched.

I also tried to run `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye` before running svn up, but this did not change anything.

So has anybody such a setup? Or some idea how to fix/debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Both of those require an interactive session, which might not given when called by `svn` (although I'm not sure about this).

A better solution might be to preset the passphrase by running `gpg-preset-passphrase` (usually in `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase` or `/usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase`), which must also be allowed in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` before by adding a line reading `allow-preset-passphrase`.

After adding the passphrase to the cache, you will be able to perform operations using GnuPG for a configurable time (which can be arbitrary long).

Comment: How do I get the cacheid / "keygrip" for the svn password to call `gpg-preset-passphrase`?